# Why can't I style the <html> element using attribute or class selectors in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

**See edit**

I am setting a `data-page` attribute on my `<html>` tag to the id of the current page. So on my login page:

`<html data-page="login">`

For some reason, IE8 is not applying any styles like these:

```
[data-page="login"] { ... }
[data-page="login"] form { ... }
[data-page="login"] form input { ... }
```

Even though it is supposed to support the attribute selector. If I change the data-page to an id, and select it using `#login`, IE8 works fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I'd like to keep the attribute selectors.

**EDIT: I've found that even trying to select with a class won't work, so it's not that. The problem seems to be that I cannot set styles on the `<html>` element at all in IE8.**

Comment: Browsers, especially those without a clue about HTML5, have trouble with data attributes and attribute selectors.

Comment: It seems to work fine in IE8 for me: http://jsbin.com/ahucor. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yeah that does work thanks. Something else then... oh god.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I am a fool, but for anyone else who stumbles across this (as it is super mysterious until you realize it), I had forgot that I was using HTML5 Boilerplate-style conditional comments on the html element, so that the template variables were only being attached to the html element in non-IE browsers.